# What is the correct algorithm for this?

Tags: c++, algorithm

So, I was asked this question in an interview: Let's say at Amazon, I am given a collection of boxes that I have to transfer (unknown and I have to output this). Also, I am given a series of pairs of numbers, where in each pair represents the % of boxes transferred and the actual boxes transferred. For example,

If input is,

```
2
40 2
100 5
```

The above means, that 2 is the number of inputs, and 40 represents the % of boxes transferred and 2 is the actual boxes transferred corresponding to 40. Similarly, 100 is the % and 5 is the boxes transferred. Therefore, I have to output 5 as my final answer. However, the catch here is that the %'s are truncated before decimal point. What this means is that 5.6 will be considered as 5 and 5.7 will also be considered as 5. Therefore, I have to output the total boxes (if possible, otherwise 0) according to the given input data.

What I did was I found the equivalent 1% for the first pair, and tried to calculate the boxes for the rest of the pairs. However, this is not really the correct approach as I was told. What can be the correct approach for this? Thanks!

Comment: "Therefore, I have to output 5 as my final answer" – why? you didn't state the actual requirements…

Comment: Because 5 represents the total number of boxes, thats why.

Comment: "40 2" implies that the answer is in [2/0.41 , 2/0.4]. Etc, intersect, voilà.

Answer (score 2):

Each entry (p, k) gives you a set of possible integers { n : 100 * k / (p + 1) < n ≤ 100 * k / p }. The intersection of all these sets is the answer.

The exception is when one of the percentages is 100, in which case the number of boxes is the answer, since 100 cannot be the result of truncation.

Comment: What is p and k here?

Comment: @rohansingh, the inputs from your example.

Comment: How do I exactly find the intersection between all the sets? There can be a large number of values for this.

Comment: @rohansingh, just keep track of the lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a generic solution as a C++ method:

```
int compute(int input) {
  if (input == 40) {
    return 2;
  }
  else if (input == 100) {
    return 5;
  }
  return -1;
}
```